# Javascript code evaluates true when conditional statement is false && true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I need help troubleshooting some JavaScript in a Rails (4.2.6) fitness application with Chartjs.  I'm getting unexpected behavior when trying to set some variables using the ternary (if) operator.

```
// f = female, m = male; first = first measurement of year; last = last measurement of year
var sex_female = "<%= @member.sex == 'Female' %>";
var sex_male = "<%= @member.sex == 'Male' %>";
var normal_body_fat_first_f;
var normal_body_fat_last_f;
var normal_body_fat_first_m;
var normal_body_fat_last_m;

normal_body_fat_first_f = sex_female && body_fat_year_first <= 24.0 ? body_fat_year_first : 24.0;
normal_body_fat_last_f = sex_female && body_fat_year_last <= 24.0 ? body_fat_year_last : 24.0;

normal_body_fat_first_m = sex_male && body_fat_year_first <= 17.0 ? body_fat_year_first : 17.0;
normal_body_fat_last_m = sex_male && body_fat_year_last <= 17.0 ?  body_fat_year_last : 17.0;
```

For testing purposes, I logged in a MALE user with the following body fat data:

```
body_fat_year_first = 15.2
body_fat_year_last = 21.9
```

Here are results from the Firefox console:

```
> sex_female
"false"
> sex_male
"true"

> normal_body_fat_first_f
"15.2"
> normal_body_fat_last_f
"21.9"

normal_body_fat_first_m
"15.2"
normal_body_fat_last_m
"17"

> body_fat_year_first <=24
true
> body_fat_year_first <= 17.0
true

> sex_female && body_fat_year_first <= 24.0
true
> sex_female && body_fat_year_last <= 24.0
true

> sex_male && body_fat_year_first <= 17.0
true
> sex_male && body_fat_year_last <= 17.0
false
```

If sex_female evaluates to "false" && body_fat_year_first <=24 evaluates to true, why isn't the false && true statement evaluating to false?

My initial thought was that sex_female is a string, which is why the statement evaluates to true.  To test this, I tried converting the strings to boolean values like this:

```
var sex_female = "<%= @member.sex == 'Female'%>" == "true";
var sex_male = "<%= @member.sex == 'Male'%>" == "true";
```

However, that change did not solve the problem:  the 'sex_male' statements are never evaluated.

What am I doing wrong?  When a male is logged in, why isn't the && operator 'short-circuiting' when it encounters the 'sex_female' part and evaluating the entire expression as false?

I'd appreciate any help and advice about why this is happening, and how I can best fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Homa Where is there an if statement in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
"false" != false
```

In other words, `"false"` is a non-empty string, which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in JavaScript, i.e. evaluates to `true`.

---

Removing the quotes around the assignment should solve this issue:

```
var sex_female = <%= @member.sex == 'Female' %>;
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Tried removing the quotes around var assignment, but unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem. It's still ignoring the male related statements. It's yielding female values for a logged in male. Hmm.